# Cloudformation auto create certficate for Application Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-acm

How to create auto certificate for the Application Load Balancer with Cloudformation? Is there any sample template?

Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

You're able to provision a certificate using cloudformation that can be used as reference in provisioning resource that requires it.

Reference: [AWS Certificate Manager - Cloudformation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-certificatemanager-certificate.html)

Reference: https://binx.io/blog/2018/10/05/automated-provisioning-of-acm-certificates-using-route53-in-cloudformation/

Comment: Just a note. This will require custom resource in CFN to be created, as the ACM certs needs to be verified. Just something worth mentioning I think.